# SQL Query to order data based on other column value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below set of data(current data), where system_id is the ID of the particular system. And pre_system_id's are ID of system where it is dependent. Now I need the order in such a way that  rows with no dependent system should come first , then rows with one dependent system come second and so on.

The current result:

```
System_ID   PRE_SYSTEM_ID1  PRE_SYSTEM_ID2  PRE_SYSTEM_ID3  PRE_SYSTEM_ID4
106          100            
105             
112          105             100             109    
100             
109          100             105        
119          100             109             105             112
102          112             109        
104          109             106
```

The actual result should be like below:

```
Order   System_ID   PRE_SYSTEM_ID1  PRE_SYSTEM_ID2  PRE_SYSTEM_ID3  PRE_SYSTEM_ID4
1          100              
2          105              
3          106              100         
4          109              100              105        
5          112              105              100            109 
6          119              100              109            105              112
7          104              109              106        
8          102              112              109            104
```

The query for the current result is simply

```
Select * from ImpactedSystem;
```

Comment: if it is in `sql` try `order by` `system_id` to your query.

Comment: can u post your query which gives you the **CURRENT DATA**

Comment: Order by won't work because I don't need data  on system_id. Its depends on pre_system_id.. current data  is from table.

Comment: @ThejKumar: show us your current query for more info

Comment: Stack its just a data from table. Select * from ImpactedSystem; it will give the current data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorting by the various PRE_SYSTEM_IDn columns using the `nulls first` clause should produce the order you want:

```
select * 
from  ImpactedSystem
order by PRE_SYSTEM_ID1 nulls first, 
         PRE_SYSTEM_ID2 nulls first,  
         PRE_SYSTEM_ID3 nulls first,  
         PRE_SYSTEM_ID4 nulls first,
         SYSTEM_ID
```

Finally sort by SYSTEM_ID, to order the values with no dependent IDs.

Comment: in 5,6 rows topic starter needed another order.

Comment: @АнатолийПредеин - hmm yes I see what you mean. I'm assuming that's a typo in the OP's editing of their desired result. However, if they have some convoluted sorting in mind they need to explain their further rules.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below query to obtain the result as well.

```
select * 
from Current_data
order by DECODE(pre_system_td1,null,1),
            DECODE(pre_system_td2,null,1),
            DECODE(pre_system_td3,null,1),
            DECODE(pre_system_td4,null,1);
```

Comment: Not the most elegant solution

Comment: Its one of the solutions. There can be many solutions to a query. This is one. I appreciate your efforts as wel